# iOS: Create dynamic contracts with iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to create a native ios application where people have to sign different contracts. Each contract contains text and input fields such as drop down and textbox. Now each contract might have different number of input fields and these might be totally different.

Any input in the best way to solve this problem? It seems like a lot of work to dynamically generate UI in code and reformat the contracts in a way that can be rendered by ios? As I cant send the pdf or doc itself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be you can have categories(sector-1,sector-2 etc) and related sample contract from. In those sample forms you can handle dynamic controls which definitely a few.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you please elaborate a bit more your suggestion? You mean break the contract into sectors with e.g. one input field pr sector?